# jquery unbind events still appearing to be live outside of functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind, unbind

I hope I can explain this well.

I have mousedown and mouseup functions within an else if statement (this allows the user to drag objects in the page and relates to pointer and mouse events running according to certain modes).

Code:

```
}else if(typeof mode !== 'undefined' && mode === 'move'){

        toolId =        'toolMove';
        this.deselectAllElems($svgContentRef);  
        fdtObj.dragMode = true;

        $('#formWrap').draggable( "option", "disabled", false ).addClass('dragCursor');
        $svgContentRef.css({ cursor: 'url(images/cursor_drag.gif),auto' });

        $('#formWrap').bind('mousedown',function() {
            $svgContentRef.css({ cursor: 'url(images/cursor_dragging.gif),auto' });
        });
        $('#formWrap').unbind('mousedown',event);

        $('#formWrap').bind('mouseup',function() {
            $svgContentRef.css({ cursor: 'url(images/cursor_drag.gif),auto' });
        });
        $('#formWrap').unbind('mouseup',event);
    }else{

        $svgContentRef.css('cursor','default');

    }
```

The problem seems to be that when I click another mode (outside of the current one) the mousedown events are still being fired.  I suspect that the unbind is not being handled correctly.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: no signature of `unbind` takes an event object as the second parameter http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

where does the variable event come from? is it the parameter passed by the handler?

If so, what you have to pass to unbind() is the reference to the same function you passed with bind() or live()

so, you could do something like this:

```
$('#formWrap').bind('mousedown',function() {
        ....
        $(this).unbind('mousedown', this);
    });
```

where `$(this) refers to $('#formWrap')` and `this refers to the function in scope`

## update

instead of having `$('#formWrap').bind('mousedown',function() {...});`
do:

```
function handler(eventObject){
   .....
   $(this).unbind('mousedown', handler);
}

$('#formWrap').bind('mousedown', handler);
```

Comment: Well this looks to be an elegant solution, but the object still appears to be bound. I've tried this `code   $('#formWrap').bind('mouseup',function() {
    $svgContentRef.css({ cursor: 'url(images/cursor_drag.gif),auto' });
    $('#formWrap').css({ cursor: 'url(images/cursor_drag.gif),auto' });
    var $unbind = $(this).unbind('mouseup', this);
    $unbind;
    alert ($unbind);
   });`       The alert is being fired when I click into another mode.

Comment: ok, sorry, you will have to separate things, then. I will update my answer

Comment: Thank you, I just about have this working, just one little issue I am trying to iron out. Thanks again, may well post later or tomorrow.

Comment: OK, I will post an answer (I hope this is OK).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete function. Everything is working in terms of the cursor options being reset when the client clicks a different mode. However within the drag mode mousedown on the drag cursor works the first time, as does mouseup, but it is then stuck on the mouseup option, i.e mousedown is not firing a second time, here is the code:

```
    this.switchDesignMode = function(mode){

    fdtObj.dragMode = false;

    $('#formWrap').draggable({ disabled: true });
    $('#formWrap').removeClass('dragCursor').css('cursor','');
    //$('#formWrap').unbind('mousedown');
    //$('#formWrap').unbind('mouseup');

    designMode =                mode;                                                                           

    var $sideRef =              this.getCurrentSideRef(),                                                       
        $svgContentRef =        this.getSvgContentRef($sideRef),                                                
        $panelTools =           $('#panelTools'),                                                               
        toolId =                'toolPointer';                                                                  

    if(typeof mode !== 'undefined' && mode === 'text'){

        toolId =                'toolText';
        this.deselectAllElems($svgContentRef);                                                                  
        $svgContentRef.css('cursor','text');                                                                    

    }else if(typeof mode !== 'undefined' && mode === 'move'){

        toolId =                'toolMove';
        this.deselectAllElems($svgContentRef);                                                                  
        fdtObj.dragMode = true;

        $('#formWrap').draggable( "option", "disabled", false ).addClass('dragCursor');
        $svgContentRef.css({ cursor: 'url(images/cursor_drag.gif),auto' });

        function handler1(eventObject){
            $svgContentRef.css({ cursor: 'url(images/cursor_dragging.gif),auto' });
            $(this).unbind('mousedown', handler1);
        }
        $('#formWrap').bind('mousedown', handler1);

        function handler2(eventObject) {
            $svgContentRef.css({ cursor: 'url(images/cursor_drag.gif),auto' });
            $(this).unbind('mouseup', handler2);
        }
        $('#formWrap').bind('mouseup', handler2);

    }else{

        $svgContentRef.css('cursor','default');                                                                 

    }

    $panelTools.find('a').removeClass('active');                                                                
    $panelTools.find('a#' + toolId).addClass('active');                                                         

};
```

(I also tried to set an unbind option at the top of the function however this did not work.

Hope this is clear. 
L

Comment: OK it's working now, had to declare handler 1 and 2 functions globally and then the bind and unbind is working.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
   $('#formWrap').bind('mousedown',function() {
        $svgContentRef.css({ cursor: 'url(images/cursor_dragging.gif),auto' });
        $(this).unbind('mousedown');
    });
```

you can also use `on` and `off` methods:

```
   $('#formWrap').on('mousedown',function() {
        $svgContentRef.css({ cursor: 'url(images/cursor_dragging.gif),auto' });
        $(this).off('mousedown');
    });
```